# Dynamically adding forms in formset not saving / Management form manual update?

Tags: jquery, python, django, forms

I've been following this [tutorial](http://whoisnicoleharris.com/2015/01/06/implementing-django-formsets.html), and the form duplication/removal part works great however, the only the first form is saved. From the formset's `data`, I know the values exist as well as that `form-TOTAL_FORMS` should be 2 (or however many) instead of 1. I assume this is why `geo_form.cleaned_data` does not contain any of the second form. I'm assuming that if `form-TOTAL_FORMS` matched then all the form data would be there. If that is correct, how do I update the management form? If there is another solution how would I enact that?

```
(Pdb) for k, v in geo_formset.data.items(): print k, v
form-0-tables test1, test2, test3
form-0-name Shelburne, Burlington, Rutland
form-1-state OR
outfile x.xlsx
form-MAX_NUM_FORMS 1000
form-0-survey ACS1
form-1-name Washington, Clackamas
form-TOTAL_FORMS 1
form-0-years 2000
form-MIN_NUM_FORMS 0
form-INITIAL_FORMS 0
form-1-region county
form-0-state VT
form-0-region place
```

Below is the view:

```
class Start(View):

    def get(self, request):
        GeoFormset = formset_factory(GeographyForm)
        CensusFormset = formset_factory(forms.CensusForm)
        geo_formset = GeoFormset()
        cen_formset = CensusFormset()
        out_form = forms.OutfileForm()
        return render(
            request,
            'start.html',
            {
                'geo_formset': geo_formset,
                'cen_formset': cen_formset,
                'out_form': out_form
            }
        )

    def post(self, request):
        GeoFormset = formset_factory(GeographyForm, min_num=1, validate_min=True, extra=0)
        CensusFormset = formset_factory(forms.CensusForm, min_num=1, validate_min=True, extra=0)
        geo_formset = GeoFormset(request.POST)
        cen_formset = CensusFormset(request.POST)
        out_form = forms.OutfileForm(request.POST)
        if geo_formset.is_valid() and out_form.is_valid() and cen_formset.is_valid():
            import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('completed'))
        else:
            return render(
                request,
                'start.html',
                {
                    'geo_formset': geo_formset,
                    'cen_formset': cen_formset,
                    'out_form': out_form
                }
            )
```

and the template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block body %}
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
    {{cen_formset.management_form}}
    {% for cen_form in cen_formset.forms %}
      <fieldset>
        <div class="census-formset">
          Select a survey: {{ cen_form.survey }} | {{ cen_form.tables }}<br>
          {{ cen_form.years }}
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    {% endfor %}
    <br>
    {{geo_formset.management_form}}
    {% for geo_form in geo_formset %}
      <fieldset>
        <div class="geo-formset">
          {{ geo_form.as_p }}
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    {% endfor %}
    <br>
    <fieldset>
      {{ out_form.as_p }}
    </fieldset>

    <input type="submit" value="OK">
  </form>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.formset/1.2.2/jquery.formset.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .remove_text{
      clear: left;
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.census-formset').formset({
        addText: 'add census',
        deleteText: 'remove',
        deleteCssClass: 'remove_text',
    });
    $('.geo-formset').formset({
        addText: 'add regions',
        deleteText: 'remove',
        deleteCssClass: 'remove_text',
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Note: I am using `Django 1.10.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have multiple formsets in the one view, you need to set the prefix parameter [(see docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#using-more-than-one-formset-in-a-view) when instantiating the formset. Otherwise there is a naming clash.

i.e. `geo_formset = GeoFormset(request.POST)` will be `geo_formset = GeoFormset(request.POST, prefix='geo')`, and similar for `CensusFormset`.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to accept @neomaic 's answer as the accepted one, as it got me to the right answer. In addition to adding the `prefix` to my formsets, I also had to update the JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.census-formset').formset({
        prefix: "{{cen_formset.prefix}}",
        addText: 'add census',
        deleteText: 'remove',
        deleteCssClass: 'remove_text',
    });
    $('.geo-formset').formset({
        prefix: "{{geo_formset.prefix}}",
        addText: 'add regions',
        deleteText: 'remove',
        deleteCssClass: 'remove_text',
    });
 </script>
```